# intersection "where LIKE" QUERY IN sql

Tags: c#, sql

what is the syntax of sql query has intersection between 2 "where Like" condition

```
string command_get_pay = "select Credit 
                            from Update_Company_Credit 
                           where ( Update_Date LIKE '%" + 8 + "%'& Update_Date LIKE 18'%" + 8 + "%')";`
```

is this true I try it but I got exception in syntax

Comment: Why did you mark the previous question as answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508024/sql-like-query-syntax

Comment: because after I read it is answer I know that you can't search for string in Datetime and I try to search in integer or datetime and it worked

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Why the backtick?

Comment: @OMG Ponies: There is a backtick at the end of the last line -- revision history seems to think you added it. Typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
SELECT
    Credit
FROM
    Update_Company_Credit
WHERE
    Update_Date LIKE '%" + 8 + "%'
    AND Update_Date LIKE 18'%" + 8 + "%'
;
```

Also, `LIKE` takes a string to use for search, but your second `LIKE` appears to be invalid... what is `18'%" + 8 + "%')"`?

**Edit:** Oh, this is C#. Still makes no sense: how are you adding a string and an integer?

Comment: I think he wants probably OR, because a column can't be 2 values at the same time

Comment: sorry 18'%" + 8 + "%')" is wrong it is only LIKE '%" + 8 + "%')"

Comment: Well, he says "intersection", which is an `AND` kind of operation. A `LIKE '%blue%' AND LIKE '%green%'` can match rows, and is different from the same statement with `OR`. His statements seem to follow this pattern, so, ideally, he should clarify which is intended...

Comment: @salamonti: That's a little clearer, but if this is C#, how are you adding a string and an integer?

Comment: normal I tried 1 'Like' condition with integer and I didn't got exception and it worked because I search in datetime type

Comment: +1: @salamonti - don't forget to vote up answers you think are worth it.  Click the arrow above the number to the left of the answer.

Comment: ooh thank you I am sorry I didn't know this information so I make is as right answer I will repair it

Answer (score 0):

the & should be probably OR?